# Using ImageSharp what's the best way to convert incoming buffer containing Bgra32 to an ImageSharp Image<Rgba24> image?

Tags: c#, imagesharp

I get `PixelFormats.Bgra32` images from UAP and WPF and I would like to know the fastest way to convert them to and from SixLabors.ImageSharp `Image<Rgba32>` images. Is there some magic "mutate" that can flip the pixel bytes after I've copied the buffer using `TryGetSinglePixelSpan`?

Comment: I'm curious as to why this question was closed. I understand it and can provide an answer.

Comment: @JamesSouth People confusing "I don't understand this question" with "this question is unclear" is an unfortunately common problem here, and one that has only gotten worse since the number of close votes was reduced.

Comment: Very disappointing to see.

Answer (score 7):

There's no shortcut for mutating an existing image but you can create a new one with the pixel format you need from the first.

```cs
Image<Rgba32> rgba;

// Load decodes
// LoadPixelData copies
// WrapMemory wraps
using (Image<Bgra32> bgra = Image.LoadPixelData<Bgra32>(...))
{
   rgba = bgra.CloneAs<Rgba32>(bgra.GetConfiguration());
}
```

You can then do whatever you need with the `Rgba32` image.